# How to interpret the hyperbolic expression « rien que ça » used in the interrogative form, as opposed to the affirmative?

Tags: expressions

I usually use the locution « rien que ça » in an affirmative sentence to emphasise what seems like an over-the-top remark. I'd say something like:

> Il est peut-être légèrement moins grand que Trump, mais c'est à s'y méprendre ! On dirait des jumeaux, **rien que ça !**

But I just heard one of my colleagues using it as an interrogative sentence, which pulled me up short.

> {I said}: Ils sont diamétralement opposés, je savais qu’ils se disputeraient de temps en temps !
>
> {My colleague replied}: Diamétralement opposés ? **Rien que ça ?**

I wonder if I should interpret its meaning somewhat differently from when it is used in the affirmative? I assume my colleague wanted to say:

> I don't think they are so different as to be polar opposites.

How would you use this expression in the interrogative like this in other examples?

Comment: I think it’s possible to interpret your colleague’s response as merely playfully/sarcastically calling you out on your hyperbolic choice of words w/out necessarily assuming that s/he doesn't totally agree (maybe even more so) with what you just said: “Polar opposites? Are you sure they’re not even more different than that?” (s/he asked sarcastically, knowing full well that would be technically impossible). Anyway I agree w/ @Kerkyra  that it’s like asking sarcastically “C’est tout?” or “Pas plus?” as one might respond to Ms Moffatt's [Je veux tout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ePtu8lq8bo).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sense is the same in your affirmative and in your interrogative examples: "rien que ça" is used in a ironical way, to point out an overstatement. The interrogative form emphasises the doubt about your choice of words "diamétralement opposés", in quite the same way that an exclamative sentence would.

> {Person 1} Mon fils vient de s'acheter une Porsche.
>
> {Person 2} Une Porsche, rien que ça !

and

> {Person 1} Mon fils vient de s'acheter une Porsche.
>
> {Person 2} Une Porsche, rien que ça ?

carry the same meaning. You can use the interrogative or exclamative form to express the surprise.

I guess the difference is that you can also use the interrogative form with a non-ironical meaning, for example with a genuine surprise:

> {Person 1} Je vais prendre une petite salade.
>
> {Person 2} Une petite salade ? Rien que ça ?

In this case, you could also use the expression "C'est tout ?". Recognizing the meaning would rely on the context. I think your colleague was ironic, unless you really were understating it with "diamétralement opposés"?

Comment: Well the exclamative can *also* be used in a non-ironical way. *Qu'est-ce que tu veux ? Rien que ça !*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of the meaning of your colleague's sentence; depending on his opinion in fact.
In my opinion, in the sentence "*Diamétralement opposés ? Rien que ça ?*", I think this means "That much ?"
Maybe your colleague thinks they are not that much "*Diamétralement opposés*".

OR

This can be a way to say that they are more than "*Diamétralement opposés*", then this would mean "Only ?" ; a way to underline what you have just said.